# Why is the background color on my bootstrap collapse panel not changing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that I haven't styled it too much but I am learning how to do it and I just want to change the background color of the question. I am also not sure as to how I can get it to not take so much room on my page.

```css
/*FAQ Page*/

.panel-title {
 font-family: freight-text-pro;

}

.panel-body {
 font-family: freight-text-pro;

}

.panel-heading {
 background-color: #FF3300;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- Panel One -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
     Where are you located?
  </a>
   </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        We are located in Boston, Massachusetts.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- Panel Two -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      Do you work with overseas/international clients?
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Yes we are open to any client in all countries.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default"><!-- Panel Three -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
     What is your average project turnaround?
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
    Though we do not like to give a specific turnaround, we do like to estimate (depending on the job) about 12-16 weeks.
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what you wants to change on hover .panel-heading background color changed

Answer (score 0):

You may try to:

- add the boostrap libraries
- change a bit your css

The snippet:

```css
/*FAQ Page*/

.panel-group .panel-default .panel-heading .panel-title {
  font-family: freight-text-pro;

}

.panel-group .panel-default .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  font-family: freight-text-pro;

}

.panel-group .panel-default .panel-heading {
  background-color: #FF3300;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- Panel One -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    Where are you located?
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                We are located in Boston, Massachusetts.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- Panel Two -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    Do you work with overseas/international clients?
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Yes we are open to any client in all countries.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default"><!-- Panel Three -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    What is your average project turnaround?
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Though we do not like to give a specific turnaround, we do like to estimate (depending on the job) about
                12-16 weeks.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When i have make "run the snippet" of your code i have the background-color in #FF3300 (if i haven't bad eyes it's orange) So you have two possibilities :

1) Change the order of your css call :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/YourStyle.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

You have to call bootstrap first -> cause html read your page in normal order.

2) If it doesn't work second option :

```
.panel-heading {
    background-color: #FF3300 !important;
}
```

If you can avoid to use the !importan it's better but sometime it's necessary. Try to do right clic, inspect element when you have css problem and check in the list if your own css is ok or if he is surclassed by bootstrap.

I hope it's will work for you. (sorry for my write-style so frenchy ^^)